# Why can't I see "edit privacy" option for my post on fb friends timeline?

Tags: facebook-timeline

I posted Happy birthday on friend timeline.
1- why that post is not visible on my time?
2- i couldn't see edit privacy option when i visited my post on friend timeline?

Comment: Previously whenever i posted anything on friend's timeline that post also appeared on my timeline. But yesterday when i posted (Happy Birthday) on friend's timeline it didn't appear on my timeline. I want to change its privacy settings but couldn't see that option even.